# Why does the i in second loop counts as 1 less than the given input by the user?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Second i in loop counts as 1 less than the given input by the user for some reason. I dont know where the i changes it's value

One way i tried to fix it is by changing

## for i in range (int(i))

to

## for i in range (int(i)+1)

Does fix the problem but idk why it is needed

```
i = input()
AliceShapeSequence = []
BobShapeSequence = []

for i in range (int(i)):
        AliceShape = input()
        AliceShapeSequence.append(AliceShape)
    
for i in range (int(i)):
        BobShape = input()
        BobShapeSequence.append(BobShape)
    
print(AliceShapeSequence)
print(BobShapeSequence)
```

Excepted both lists to have 3 values but AliceShapeSequence has 3 and BobShapeSequence has 2 (depends on the input i used 3 for this example)

Comment: The answer tn your other, recently deleted question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60684/deleting-lines-of-code-in-a-text-editor

Comment: Oh thank you :). I actually just found the solution on another post so I just deleted my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually quite an interesting question. Let's step through what's happening here.

```
i = input()
```

Say your user enters `3`. Now `i` is `3`, as expected.

```
for i in range (int(i)):
```

First, `range(int(i))` is called. Python's `range`, when called with one argument, creates a range from `0` (inclusive) to that argument (exclusive). Since `i` is `3`, this creates a range containing the values `0`, `1`, and `2`.

Now, you start iterating, with an iteration variable `i`.`i` is first set to `0`, then the code block is run, `1`, and the code block is run, then `2`, and the code block is run for a final time.

However, there's a trick. Due to Python's scoping rules, you iteration variable `i` is actually the *same* variable as the global variable `i`. So during iteration you were updating the *global* `i` value to `0`, then `1`, then `2`. So when we start the next loop:

```
for i in range (int(i)):
```

`range(int(i))` is `range(2)`, which creates a range with the elements `0` and `1`—not what you wanted.

To fix this, change the iteration variables to something else—perhaps `j`, as another answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `i` is global any python function or class defined in this module is able to access this variable:

Your key value and your input variables are at the same `scope`.

So you input `3` and the loops starts counting at `0` to after the loop `i` is counted up to `2` after the first loop so the loop will start with `2`:

```
i = input()
AliceShapeSequence = []
BobShapeSequence = []

for x in range (int(i)):
        AliceShape = input()
        AliceShapeSequence.append(AliceShape)

for x in range (int(i)):
        BobShape = input()
        BobShapeSequence.append(BobShape)

print(AliceShapeSequence)
print(BobShapeSequence)
```

Just change upcounting key to other variable name you are fine.

To make it easy to understand just run:

```
i = 3
AliceShapeSequence = []
BobShapeSequence = []

for i in range (int(i)):
        AliceShape = i
        AliceShapeSequence.append(AliceShape)
        print("first loop: i = {0} after {1} loop cycle".format(i, i+1))

for i in range (int(i)):
        BobShape = i
        BobShapeSequence.append(BobShape)
        print("second loop: i = {0} after {1} loop cycle".format(i, i+1))


print(AliceShapeSequence)
print(BobShapeSequence)
```

Answer (score 0):

The i in the for loop is updating every time it runs.

```
range(5) // gives you 0-4
```

i is set to 4 on the last cycle of the loop. Use a different variable name.

Answer (score -1):

I ran your code, but changed `for i in range(int(i))` into `for j in range(int(i))` for both cases and then it behaved as expected.

You shouldn't use the same variable names, otherwise you may have issues with unexpected side effects.